# Serenity jbehave issue when using multiple scenario outlines in a single .feature file

Tags: jbehave, gherkin, thucydides, serenity-bdd

We are using Serenity with JBehave. We are facing issues when we have multiple scenario outlines with examples table in a single `.feature` file.

We have something like this in our Feature file:

```
Scenario Outline: title 1
Given
When
Then
Examples:
|data|

Scenario Outline: title 2
Given 2
When 2
Then 2
Examples:
|Data|
```

In this case after executing *Examples* of Scenario 1, it is considering Scenario outline 2 also as an input to scenario 1 example table, instead of treating it as a new scenario.

This is how the output looks like:

```
 Scenario Outline: title 1
 Given
 When
 Then
 Examples:
 |data|
 |Scenario Outline: title 2|
 |Given 2|
 |When 2|
 |Then 2|
 |Examples:|
 |Data|
```

Here are the versions of plugins:

- jbehave.core.version - 3.9.5;
- serenity.version - 1.0.47;
- serenity.jbehave.version - 1.0.21

Can someone please help resolve this?

**Note:** I have seen posts where people had same issues when using *scenario* with examples table rather than using *scenario outline* with examples. Here I am using *scenario outline* only, but still have the same issue.